# Озеро, олень, осень — этимология

Tags: историческая-фонетика

Каково историческое произношение слов езеро (озеро), елень (олень), есень (осень), пелынь (полынь) и стенати (стонать)?
Там где буква "е" читается как [йэ] или как [йо]?
Если первый вариант, то как тогда можно объяснить фонетическое преобразовнаие [йэ] -> [о]?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, у вас заголовок не соответвует названию. Этимология и фонетика - разные вещи.
Во-вторых, вы в одну кучу валите совершенно разные случаи.
В-третьих, о каком языке и какой эпохе вы говорите?
Наконец, все доступные сведения есть в любом профильном словаре, добавить к ним нечего.

В русском - осень, в церковнославянском  и древнерусском - есень, в праславянском вообще фонетика была другой, сам набор гласных отличался от современного.

ЙЕ<>0 (в "открытом спереди" слоге) это явление русского языка, в большинстве славянских там Э, но это колебание ограничено четкими позиционными рамками. В любом случае переход О в ЙЕ (или обратный) никак не может быть истолкован с тех же позиций, что и пара полынь-пелынь. С последним вообще не очень понятна этимология, а без неё трудно судить об "историческом" произношении. Если предположить, что слово восходит к морфу "пламя", то исходным должно быть именно "полынь" (или, менее вероятно, пЪлынь). Но это такая древность и такие дебри...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91777/discussion-on-answer-by-behemothus-----).